# What is the current state-of-the-art in assembling hybrid transcriptomes?

Tags: assembly, transcriptome, pacbio

We are considering attempting de novo assembly of a species transcriptomes (i.e. without a reference genome) using the combined NGS outputs of Iso-seq and Illumina.

One example I saw ([Li et al 2017](https://www.nature.com/articles/celldisc201731)), used the standard PacBio tools to assemble a transcriptome, followed by correcting the assembled sequence using a tool called `proovread`, followed by `cd-hit-est` and then `cogent`.

Would this be considered a reasonable pipeline or is there an alterative recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to run *Trinity* using the `--long_reads` option, which allows you to provide an error-corrected fastq file for anchoring reads to a transcript isoform. The reads are then clustered per-isoform, and assembled, in a similar fashion to what's done with genome-guided Trinity:

https://github.com/trinityrnaseq/trinityrnaseq/wiki/Running-Trinity

```
Trinity --seqType fq --max_memory 50G --long_reads corrected_pacbio_reads.fa --left reads_1.fq  --right reads_2.fq --CPU 6
```

*Disclaimer: I have contributed code to Trinity at some time in the distant past*